# Magento AJAX Table reload on Product Page

Tags: ajax, magento

I've been battling with this for a while now. I have a configurable product which is set up correctly and succesffuly. I also have a table which is produced based on the size and quantity available for each version of this product, based on the children. See here: dev4.printpartnerships.com/flyer-printing

This table currently is rendered on page load then uses jQuery to swap it depending on the drop-down box selection. The problem is it's a bit slow and I need to dynamically reload JUST the table depending on the drop-down. For example, when drop-down 3, paper, is selected it potentially reloads the table. This is done by these 2 functions and this call:

```
<div id="matrix-container">
    <?php $attributeSetName = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName(); ?>
    <?php $stock = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('stock'); ?>
    <?php if($stock->usesSource()):?>
    <?php $options = $stock->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); ?>
        <?php foreach ($options as $k => $v):?>
            <?php $options[$k] = $v['label']; ?>
            <?php $stockQuery = $options[$k].' '.$attributeSetName; ?>
            <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getTable($_product, $stockQuery); ?>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif;?>
</div>
```

And the functions here:

```
    public function getMatrixData($requiredAttributeIds = null, $product = null, $stock)
{   
    Varien_Profiler::start('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    $this->_usedProducts = '_cache_instance_products';
    if ($this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_usedProducts)) {
        if (is_null($requiredAttributeIds)
            and is_null($this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_configurableAttributes))) {
            $this->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
            Varien_Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
            return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_usedProducts);
        }

        $usedProducts = array();
        $collection = $this->getUsedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$stock.'%'));

        if (is_array($requiredAttributeIds)) {
            foreach ($requiredAttributeIds as $attributeId) {
                $attribute = $this->getAttributeById($attributeId, $product);
                if (!is_null($attribute))
                    $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), array('notnull'=>1));
            }
        }

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $usedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_usedProducts, $usedProducts);
    }
    Varien_Profiler::stop('CONFIGURABLE:'.__METHOD__);
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_usedProducts);
}

public function getTable($product = false, $stock) 
{
    if (!$product) return false;
        $childProducts = $this->getMatrixData(null, $product, $stock);
        $x = array();
        $r = '';

            foreach ($childProducts as $children){
                $x[$children->getAttributeText('quantity')][$children->getAttributeText('size')] = array('id'=>$children->getId(), 'price'=>number_format($children->getPrice(),'2'), 'name'=>$children->getName());
            }
        ksort($x);
        $r .= '<table id="'.strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$stock)).'" class="matrix"><tr><th></th>';

            foreach(array_keys(current($x)) as $size){
                $r .= '<th>'.$size.'</th>';
            }
        $r .= '</tr>';

            foreach($x as $quantity => $data){
                $r .= '<tr><th>'.$quantity.'</th>';
                    foreach($data as $item){
                        $r .= '<td><a href="/checkout/cart/add?product='.$item[id].'" title="Add '.$item[name].' to basket">£'.$item[price].'</a></td>';
                    }
                $r .= '</tr>';
            }
        $r .= '</table>';
        return $r;
    }
```

This works fine as it is and the tables load perfectly, however I want to AJAX them, by sending the drop-down values as data to an AJAX script and reloading the table, rather than loading all the tables on page-load and showing/hiding. I've tried with AJAX before in Magento and had nothing but problems, I wondered if someone could give me a real-world example that I can edit or whatever to fix my problem.

As you can see I have all the code and logic, it's just AJAX'ing it to make it reload rather than jQuery to show/hide.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't know your goal but you can use jQuery data-table which is available most things that you want. [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/)

Comment: Hi Oguz, that looks OK but my problem isn't the data table itself, as that works just fine (see my example page) it's working it in with Magento to send an AJAX request. As I say I've tried this before in Magento just calling simple variables and get method errors etc usually pointing to such things like the necessary classes aren't loaded. That was on a previous attempt though.

Comment: How about load all necessary values then filter by selection to eliminate performance problem.

Comment: Hi Oguz, My concern is there are a lot of necessary values, hence the performance issue. Can you explain in more detail what you mean? I need to have it as a matrix table on my example page, that table structure is not able to change.

Comment: I mean, in the example that I gaved you ( DataTables ) there is on-the-fly filter capabilities. So, you can query all options of the product then filter by jQuery ( select box ).

Comment: Hi Oguz, I don't think that's really suitable as loading all the options in one hit will severly reduce performance. This is more a Magento based question than how to get the data and format it as I already have the data, formatted perfectly. I just need to reload the whole table with new data on selection of a drop-down via AJAX.

Comment: You should create controller and action, send needed data to it and refresh div with returned html. I don't see such code here. How do you wish load something by ajax without controller and action?

Comment: Zyava can you show me how I should create a controller and action please?

Comment: What I mean is, is there a guide or similar I can follow?

Comment: @TomDavison, watch here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/modulecreator.html This module, once installed, will enable you to create modules with proper structure.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a controller and an action, and have the ajax request go through there. And create blocks and a layout if you want.

Here's a very simple example of it: http://subesh.com.np/2009/11/working-with-ajax-in-magento/

It links to an extension that you can use as a base: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajaxify-8411.html